# Calculating dBFS for I/Q

Tags: digital-communications, analog-to-digital, software-defined-radio

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the dBFS for a complex input. I have an AD9361 part which has a 16-bit A/D and I believe outputs I and Q samples. Now I know you can calculate the dBFS for a real valued 16 bit signal as

`20log10(abs(sample)/32768).`

But I don't fully understand how to incorporate a second data stream into this calculation.

My overall goal is to calculate the dBFS of the incoming signal and use it to compare against a set-point dBFS value for an AGC. and to adjust front-end attenuators as necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sensible way here is to realize that each complex sample has a magnitude $|z|=\left\lvert \Re z + j \Im z\right\rvert = \sqrt{\left(\Re z\right)^2+\left(\Im z\right)^2}$.

In your case, the maximum non-clipping amplitude is $2^{15}$ (the maximum-power samples are on a circle around the origin).

Therefore, you'd calculate the magnitude of a sample, and compare that to $2^{15}$ to get your relation to full scale.

Comment: I had thought about this but the concern I have about this method is that the magnitude can be greater than $2^{15}$ giving me a positive dBFS. I.e. if both I and Q are full scale $\sqrt{32767^2 + 32767^2} = 46339$ And maybe that's okay?

Comment: Yes, but if that happens, that signal would be "clipping" if it had any other phase, so that's not a "valid" signal.

Comment: I think I see, but to clarify, are you implying that the ADC literally cannot give you a full scale signal on both I and Q? Or that any magnitude greater than $2^{15}$ would imply 0 dBFS for my calculations?

Comment: the ADC might. But that signal would be more than the amplitude that was representable at every phase, and hence "as good as clipped"

Comment: I see, I just added an edit to my previous comment. It sounds like I should treat that signal as 0dBFS.

Comment: When dealing with quadrature sampling I have used dBFS (DC) or similar to distinguish the 3 dB difference from where a sine wave would clip with a real signal to the usable full scale radius for a complex signal.

Comment: oh, that's a useful convention, @DanBoschen

Comment: @DanBoschen could you elaborate a little bit on that method?

Comment: I made it up but had to clarify that on ADC related graphs that apply to either complex or real signals as the power for the sine wave ar full scale is 3 dB below the power for the IQ signal. The power level of the IQ signal at full scale is the same as a DC signal since as far as magnitude goes both are constant

Comment: But as Marcus said the usable area is always inside a circle so even though the ADC could go beyond at 45 degrees for example you typically never would set an operating point there.

Comment: The power for the IQ signal is 3dB higher because,assuming a 16 bit ADC, $20log_{10}(\sqrt{32767^2 + 32767^2})=20log_{10}(\sqrt{2*32767^2})=20log_{10}(\sqrt{2})+20log_{10}(\sqrt{32767^2})=3dB + 20log_{10}(32767)$ right? But wouldn't this 3dB offset only be there if there is roughly the same power on I and Q? If most of the power is on I and very minimal power on Q, then the power levels for the sine wave and for the IQ signal will be approx. equal.

Comment: We are referring to the power that would be consistently full scale so it is the power of the maximum vector given by sqrt(I^2+Q^2) at any angle —- which is the maximum of either I or Q channels

Comment: (At full scale it must be able to rotate over all angles without clipping; anything beyond that is beyond full scale)